# Code to create a redirection after login?

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I get this code to create a  redirection after login.
I see no error but it doesn't work. No errors, it just do nothing at all.

I added this code to functions.php in my child theme.

```
/*******************************
    REDIRECTION
*********************************/

add_action('wp_head','redirect_admin');
function redirect_admin(){
  if(is_admin()&&!current_user_can('level_10')){
    wp_redirect(WP_HOME.'/quote-list/');
    die; // You have to die here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) hook.

```
function redirect_admin( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){

    //is there a user to check?

    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {

            $redirect_to = WP_HOME.'/quote-list/'; // Your redirect URL
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_admin', 10, 3 );
```

Example taken from [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)

Also is_admin() does not check if the user is an administrator but if the administration panel is being displayed.